# For my UTF-8 not working

Tags: php, html, utf-8, utf8-decode

This is a part of my code:

```
$content = ' ';
$content .= '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/></meta>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<div class="all_block">';
```

Don't work UTF-8 but it is set I don't understand where is my problem
This is an example of text: 'ja?i ku?ol har? lerp�'
Help me please!

Comment: are you getting the data from a database?

Comment: have you echo $content

Comment: yes..but is database is normal storing

Comment: what do you mean by normal storing? you can't store utf8 data on a database with latin collation. what is the collation being used in your database?

Comment: ofcourse you can. but its not the right way, because when you retrieve the data it won't be in utf8

Comment: Just a note on the side: you're producing invalid html with your code sample. You're closing the meta tag twice and as meta tags should be in your head, there shouldn't be a div in your $content as well...

Comment: how are you echoing the content from your db?

Answer (score 0):

[image]You have to set content type header in php.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$content = ' ';
$content .= '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
```

And check if the correct encoding is visible in the response header.

Comment: Where I need to add this?

Comment: You can add the header in the php script before you display your content.

Comment: I solved it the solution was to add before query : mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");